# How to use 'pkg_add -uu' to upgrade all packages?

Tags: package-management, netbsd

According to [NetBSD's wiki](https://wiki.netbsd.org/pkgsrc/how_to_upgrade_packages/) I can use `pkg_add -uu` to upgrade packages. However, when I attempt to use `pkg_add -uu` it results in an error.

```
pkg_add -uu
pkg_add: missing package name(s)
...

pkg_add -uu *
pkg_add: no pkg found for `*`, sorry
...

pkg_add -uu all
pkg_add: no pkg found for `all`, sorry
...
```

I've tried to parse the [`pkg_add` man page](https://man.netbsd.org/pkg_add.1) but I can't tell what the command it to update everything.

I can't use `pkg_chk` because its not installed, and I can't get the package system to install it:

```
pkg_chk -b
pkg_chk: command not found

pkg_add pkg_chk
pkg_add: no pkg found for `pkg_chk`, sorry
```

What is the secret command to get the OS to update everything?

Comment: Do you have pkg_path setup properly? also what is out put for pkg_info -a

Comment: pkg_add(1) needs a package name in all invocations. I assume you have a PKG_PATH set, what is it's value?

Comment: @Eric - the value of `PKG_PATH` is `ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/packages/NetBSD/amd64/7.0/All`.

Answer (score 1):

First off see the [quickstart for using pkgsrc at http://www.pkgsrc.org/#index1h1](http://www.pkgsrc.org/#index1h1)

For more details see [Using Pkgsrc: Using binary packages](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/using.html#using-pkg)

However I would recommend using [`pkgin`](http://pkgin.net/), especially if you will only be using binary packages (i.e. not building packages from pkgsrc itself).  Once you have `$PKG_PATH` set correctly in your shell environment (see the instructions in the [quickstart](http://www.pkgsrc.org/#index1h1) section) you should be able to run `pkg_add pkgin` and continue with [pkgin Usage](http://pkgin.net/#usage) (though note the value of your specific `$PKG_PATH` is what you want to put in the `repositories.conf` file -- the one in the usage section is just an example).

BTW, the wiki article you link to is out of date in a number of respects.  The meaning of `-u` has changed slightly since NetBSD-6 -- in 7.0 and newer it no longer has any special meaning if it is given more than once.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Two month later I'm back on a BSD cycle. When I search for terms like "how to update NetBSD", I land on my own question. To answer your questions, the program `pkgin` is missing, and results in a *"command not found"*. `PKG_PATH` is set `ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/packages/NetBSD/amd64/7.0/All`. How can I specify a "please just work switch" to `pkg_add`? I don't care what it uses for defaults as long as it works. How can NetBSD be legendary for security if it can't even patch itself out of the box? It reminds me of Microsoft software in the 1990s. Its worse than Windows 95.

Comment: You didn't run `pkg_add pkgin` yet, did you?

Comment: BTW, NetBSD security is about good *design*, not about patching.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `pkg_add: no pkg found for `pkgin`, sorry`.

Comment: So, you must have unset PKG_PATH or otherwise changed it before trying that?  I just tried it with the PKG_PATH you showed and it worked fine for me.

Comment: `$PKG_PATH` is set for me (and I know this for sure as running `echo $PKG_PATH` before and after running `pkg_add -u` returns the correct URL to packages) and I get the same error as jww when running `pkgin -u` or `pkg_add -u` on NetBSD 7.1.

Comment: `echo` won't tell you whether a variable is set in the shell environment, or just exists as an ordinary shell variable.  To tell what's in the environment you can use the `env` command, perhaps along with `grep` or such to search for just the one variable.  To make sure a shell variable is also set in the environment you must export it:  `export PKG_PATH` as is documented in the quickstart instructions.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that the  article is outdated. I think this is the now one of the worst problems of this bad documented BSD's.  You google for a solution and you retrieve old articles only good enough to screw up your system even more.

Comment: "NetBSD security is about good design, not about patching".  No design is 100% secure in the modern world.  A good system (even a bad one) needs to have a simple way to keep its software free of the current threats.